# Interpretation of difference in difference with a trend break term included

Tags: regression, econometrics, interpretation, difference-in-difference

If I expand a difference in difference to the following type of specification:

\begin{split}
y_{c,t} = \beta_1(\tau*treat_c) + \beta_2(post_t * treat_c) + \beta_3(post_t*treat_c*\tau) + \mu_c + \eta_{t} + \epsilon_{ct}
\end{split}

where if $\beta_1=\beta_3=0$ collapses to the standard two way fixed effect/difference in difference specification (let c = county and t = year, and the latter three terms are the county and time fixed effects, respectively and then the error term). $\tau$ is a linear time trend. I understand that this is now allowing the treatment counties to have differential linear pre trends ($\beta_1$), and allowing the treatment to have a trend break, so the effect of treatment at time $\tau$ is given by:

$\beta_2 + \beta_3*\tau$

So my question is, say I plug in $\tau$ = 2. Is $\beta_2 + \beta_3*2$ giving me the effect $\textit{at}$ year 2, or is it giving me the cumulative effect of treatment up to year 2?

Comment: What is $\tau$ in this example? A linear time trend?

Comment: Yes it is, sorry about that. I will edit the question to clarify that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model exhibits some redundancies. In practice, we typically multiply $\mu_c$ with the linear term. The treatment dummy will drop out of the model depending upon how you order your variables, but it shouldn't matter with respect to the identification of the difference-in-differences coefficient. Here is the equation I see most often estimated in practice:

\begin{equation}
y_{ct} = \beta_c(\mu_{c} \times \tau) + \mu_{c} + \eta_{t} + \delta(T_c \times P_t ) + \epsilon_{ct}
\end{equation}

where each unit $c$ receives its own unique time trend, hence why $\beta_c$ is $c$-subscripted. In the foregoing equation, the treatment effect is given by $\delta$, even in the presence of a unit-specific time trend. If you've seen applied work where the time trend was multiplied with $T_c$ and $P_t$ then please provide a reference. I have yet to see this executed in practice.

As far as setting $\tau = 2$, I see three possible scenarios. The first scenario is a time trend variable that is set at a particular value for all observations. I don't think this is what you're proposing since the trend term is now time invariant and will drop out of the model; it is collinear with the unit fixed effects.

The second scenario is a trend term that is binned at a particular value (i.e., $\tau = 1, \bar{2}$). In other words, $\tau$ is assumed to be constant once units reach the second time period (i.e., $\tau = 1, 2, ..., 2$). In this setting, you're assuming each unit's trend is linear up to a specific point. I don't think this is what you're proposing either, but it isn't outside the realm of possibilities.

The third scenario is manually setting $\tau = 2$ inside of the model formula and interacting it with each unit—separately. The model evaluates any instance where $\tau = 2$ as a time shock. The indicator for the second time period is collinear with the time fixed effects. Note how you're no longer estimating unit-specific linear time trends. Instead, this is more of a unit-year effect. Instead of a common shock experienced by all units (i.e., time effect), you're now allowing each unit to have its own effect in 2011. For example, the shock in 2011 may vary *across jurisdictions*. This is not how we estimate accumulating treatment effects.

The interaction of $\tau$ with the traditional difference-in-differences product term is curious. For instance, $P_t$ is a post-treatment indicator. Assuming you acquired serial observations on units before treatment, then I assume $P_t$ switches on in a later period, much later than the second time period. Typically we want to observe how effects accumulate in the *post-period*.

Now suppose you want the treatment effect at year 2, which I assume is the year before the real exposure of interest, then interact $T_c$ with a time dummy (i.e., $P_{t = 2011}$). If this is a period *before* some intervention, then it is, technically, a placebo treatment. In other words, we shouldn't be observing strong non-zero effects before the treatment actually begins!

Demonstrating "cumulative" treatment effects is vastly different than including unit-specific linear time trends. If you're estimating the latter, then I recommend multiplying a linear trend with your unit dummies. Do not interact the linear term with all variables in your model.